# Show react calendar on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-calendar` package on my react app. Placing `<Calendar/>` on the file gives the open calendar on the frontend.

But I want to display the calendar if the user clicks the input field:

```
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Start Date</label>
        <input type="text"/>
        <Calendar style={{display: "none"}} />
      </div>
```

I tried through inline style to hide the calendar component and change on click. But the calendar doesn't hide with inline css also.

Gone through documentation also but didn't find any help.

Comment: 1. use a state variable like `showCal: false` 2. conditionally render the calendar `{this.state.showCal && <Calendar />}` 3. add `onFocus` to the input, and use it to change the showCal state to true. (react works differently than you're used to, it's all based on state and doesn't manipulate the DOM directly)

Comment: I have 2 calendar component. I assume with this approach both calendar will be shown at once . Should i declare different state for  both calendar ??

Comment: Yes, that's how it works :)

Answer (score 4):

It will be best you create a wrapper component around your calendar and input. This way it manages its own *showCalendar* state and can be reused elsewhere.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

const ReactCalendarDemo = ({ date, setDate }) => {
  const [showCalendar, setShowCalendar] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = value => {
    setDate(value);
    setShowCalendar(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={date.toLocaleDateString()}
        onFocus={() => setShowCalendar(true)}
      />
      <Calendar
        className={showCalendar ? "" : "hide"}
        value={date}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReactCalendarDemo;
```

You pass in your current date value and its setter as props.

Then you can toggle display in your CSS style using the *hide* class

```
.react-calendar.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality, integrate the `react-calendar` library beneath the input field. Position the calendar using CSS with `position: absolute`. Utilize an event listener on the document to detect clicks outside the component, toggling the calendar's visibility accordingly.

First create child component: `CalendarInput`. Here's a simplified example:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";
import moment from "moment";

const CalendarInput = ({date, setDate}: {
    date: Date;
    setDate: (value: any, event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}) => {
    const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
    const calendarRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleDocumentMousedown = (event: MouseEvent) => {
            if (
                calendarRef.current &&
                !calendarRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)
            ) {
                setFocused(false);
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleDocumentMousedown);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleDocumentMousedown);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleChange = (value: any, event: any) => {
        setDate(value, event);
        setFocused(false);
    };

    const handleInputClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        setFocused(true);
    };

    return (
        <div className="w-full" ref={calendarRef}>
            <input
                className="input-default"
                value={moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY").toString()}
                onClick={handleInputClick}
            />
            {focused && (
                <div className="calendar-container">
                    <Calendar
                        className="absolute"
                        value={date}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default CalendarInput;
```

Then in your parent component add :

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
<CalendarInput date={date} setDate={setDate} />
```